# Build only SSDT projects in the VS solution using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, sql-server-data-tools, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a VS solution with several projects including WCF Services, .NET Core APIs and two SSDT projects. To enable CI/CD for these projects with Azure DevOps on VSTS, I've created two build definitions so far; one for .NET Core Web APIs and another for the SSDT projects. SSDT build definition was created using the .NET Desktop application template. However, it fails at sometime because it tries to build the other projects in the solution as well. How do I make sure that only the SSDT projects are build under this definition?

Answer (score 1):

> Build only SSDT projects in the VS solution using Azure DevOps

To achieve this, we could use two Visual Studio build task to build those two SSDT projects directly instead of the solution file `.sln`.

1. Unlink the `**\*.sln` in the Visual Studio build task and select the first SSDT project file `.csproj`:
   [image]
2. Add another Visual Studio build task and select the second SSDT project file `.csproj`:

   [image]

Comment: I actually did something somewhat similar, which is to add a separate solution file to include the DB projects. BTW, your images are not visible.